# Using randomisation tests for population data - question on time dependence and effect size

Tags: population, permutation-test

I have been using randomization tests on population (as opposed to sample) data and would like to double check that my methodology is correct and get advice on how to expand my analysis.

**Some background on data:**

I have monthly data on the ethnic make-up of the parliamentary cabinets of 6 African nations, over 20 years. The data includes how many people from each ethnic group are in the cabinet and the overall number of people in the cabinet. From this I have calculated the proportion of the cabinet represented by each particular ethnic group, as a percentage.

The ethnic groups can be classified into descriptive groups, called EPR groups, such as dominant, senior partner, discriminated, etc. So, for example, a cabinet of 6 ethnicities might have one dominant group, two senior partners, and three discriminated groups represented. I have also calculated the proportion of the cabinet represented by these groups (5 posts occupied in a 25-person cabinet would be 20%).

Please see a small subset of the data below:

[image]

The data in question can be seen as the full population – I am not trying to make inferences about other countries, or about what might happen in the future. Rather, I am trying to see what effects can be seen within my dataset and determine whether these observed effects are down to chance or are indicative of a real effect.

I have various hypotheses I am trying to test. One of these which I will outline is testing whether - for a particular EPR category in groups G = {dominant, senior partner, junior partner, discriminated, powerless} - there is a difference in their representation in the cabinet (proportion of cabinet places held), for different overall cabinet size. Cabinet sizes can be split into small, medium or large.

More rigorously:

Define mg,S as the mean proportion of cabinet places held by a EPR group g over all countries and months where the cabinet is of size s. S = {small, medium, or large}.

I want to test whether mg,small ≠ mg,large for a particular EPR group g.

As I have the full population data, I do not think regular hypothesis testing is appropriate, as we know the true population means already and are not trying to make inferences about them from a sample. Instead, I decided to use randomisation testing to determine whether observed effects are down to random chance.

My methodology is as follows (for comparing small and large cabinets):
1)  Pull each observation for the EPR group g in question (e.g. ‘senior partner’), along with which cabinet size grouping the observation fits in to, as shown below. 
[image]

2)  Calculate the difference between the true means for each cabinet size grouping S. Call this mdifftrueg,S.

3)  Scramble the proportions of cabinet places among all the observations (so there is mixing between cabinet sizes).

4)  For this scrambled data, calculate mdiffg,(small,large) = mg,small – mg,large and add it to array A.

5)  Repeat steps 3 and 4 n times (I used 5000).

6)  Plot the calculated differences in A as a histogram RandomDist. The CLT tells us the data should look approximately normal, as it does (see picture below).

7)  Calculate the 2.5th and 97.5th percentile for RandomDist.

8)  If our mtrueg,(small,large) is above the 97.5th percentile, or below the 2.5th percentile, conclude that the true observed difference in means is unlikely to be occur by chance, and hence we have evidence that the proportion of representation for the particular EPR group varies between the two cabinet size groups tested.

My intuition about this approach is that, if there is no difference between the two cabinet size groupings (when it comes to group g representation), then the observations for both the small and large cabinets are effectively from the same population. Thus by repeatedly scrambling the data and taking sample statistics of difference in means, we should be building up a distribution of our sample statistic under a kind of null hypothesis. If our true population statistic for the unscrambled data lies outside/at the far edges of the generated distribution, then it seems unlikely that the population statistic is from this distribution, giving evidence to the idea that the different cabinet sizes are different populations. The histogram RandomDist generated by the differences of the scrambled data is below, with the 97.5th percentile and 2.5th percentile outlined by the blue dotted lines, mtrueg,(small,large) is shown by the red solid line. From this can I conclude that the presence of group g in small and large cabinets is significantly different?
[image]

In my mind this is similar to looking at p-values. The generated distribution is our null hypothesis distribution, and the probability of our true population statistic occurring from this distribution is our p-value.

I have a few concerns about the validity of this approach:

1)  Does it matter that many of the observations are for the same country, EPR group and cabinet size, just at different points in time? This would mean that the observations are not completely independent, as the composition of a cabinet one month is highly related to what it was the previous month. Is this temporal aspect of the data an issue?

2)  Does it matter that there might be a large difference between the numbers of observations for different cabinet sizes? For example, if there are 100 data points for dominant groups in small cabinets and 700 for dominant groups in large cabinets, does the idea of scrambling the data still work? My intuition on this is that since our generated distribution assumes that the two populations are the same, this should not matter. However, this is just a hunch and I am unsure whether this changes what I can conclude from the test.

I would also like to know how to expand upon this approach in the following ways.

**Effect size**

Say I want to not just see if the representation of g1 ∈ G is significantly different between small and large cabinets, but to do the same for another category within the same set, g2 ∈ G.  If both g1 and g2 have significantly different levels of representation in small and large cabinets, is there a way for me to rank the effect size?

In short, if the difference for both g1 and g2 is significant and if mdiffTrueg1,(small,large) > mdiffTrueg2,(small,large), does this show that g1 gets a larger change in representation between cabinet sizes than g2?

My intuition says that I can compare effect size by literally comparing the means. If mdiffTrueg1,(small,large) =2.4 and mdiffTrueg2,(small,large) = 1.7, and both fall just above 97.5th percentile for their respective generated RandomDist data, then we see a larger effect for g1 (a larger change in representation between S=small and S=large).

**Perform analysis with more than 1 category**

According to this link, I can use ANOVA simulations to increase the number of groups of data (e.g. small cabinet, large cabinet, medium cabinet), but can I expand the analysis to a factorial design?

For example, in addition to EPR groups G, there is another category for all observations which outlines an ethnic group’s political allegiance p ={opposition, incumbent, unaligned}.

Say we see that mdiffTrueg1,(small,large) is large and significant, but most g1 observations are also  K=incumbent, it could be that the difference in means is being driven by each observation’s K value rather than their g1. Is there a way for me to disentangle the effect of each variable?

I am relatively new to statistics and working with unusual data so please let me know if anything needs to be clarified.
Thanks in advance for your help.